# Can Captain America be killed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, captain-america

This question comes from watching a number of the MCU movies starring Captain America and seeing all of the buildings, airplanes, high places, bombs, etc that he has been thrown through, blown up by, punched through, jumped from etc without being killed. Yeah I know he is a super soldier but at times it seems that he is more like superman than a superhuman... So can he be killed? Or is he the human version of Superman?

P.S. Just wanted to add that I have never read any of the comics so if this question is answered there... I don't know about it :).

Comment: For starters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Captain_America

Comment: Well there you go - the comics had the answer all along.

Comment: If he couldn't die, he wouldn't need the shield.

Comment: [Superman can be killed.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman)

Comment: @RogueJedi I thought the shield was more of a beat the bad guy up thing...

Comment: @Jonah Well yes with Kryptonite and all that.... but the question was about captain america...

Comment: Fine, I'll answer this....

Comment: It's a nice coincidence to have this question asked a few weeks after Civil War was released to public, since the death of Captain America appears at the end of these events in the comics.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo I actually just watched Captain America and after seeing all the things that happen to with without him even sort of being hurt I wondered it he could even be killed...

Comment: @Rincewind I wondered the same while watching the movies. The most impressive part, IMO, was is jump from the elevator in Captain America 2, and I was surprised asking myself "If this cannot kill it, how can he be killed ?"

Comment: Related: [Is Captain America super-human?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87079/is-captain-america-super-human)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, and through mundane means

In particular, in *Captain America #25*, he died from a gunshot wound. You can't get much more mundane than that.

[image]

[image]
Of course, he comes back through a  plot gimmick, but that is only to be expected.

Or in a different continuity (*Punisher Kills the Marvel Universe*), he is also shot:

[image]

Of course, that's a terrible comic, but the fact remains: Captain America can be killed by normal means. The examples I gave are from comics, principally because Captain America has not yet died in the MCU, but they illustrate the basic principle.

He can survive much longer falls than an average person, endure much more grievous wounds, and so forth, but he *can* be felled by a simple bullet.

Captain America usually relies on his speed and shield to deflect bullets, **since they pose a genuine threat to him.** **He wouldn't waste his time deflecting bullets if they were harmless to him.**

Of course, given his more-than-human toughness and powers of recovery, you'd want to shoot him many times, at close range, or in the head in order to ensure that he died.

Comment: Well, with regard to "He wouldn't waste his time deflecting bullets if they were harmless to him.", Wonder Woman deflects them, too, despite them being harmless to her.. But, then, I suppose she has [better reason](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NcCGcubFaTA/VSCJdb4ejiI/AAAAAAAADdc/gENpwpNJIUE/s1600/Bullet_Bounce.jpg) :)

Comment: @KHW - Well, they’ve been all of the map with her. In the old days, she wasn’t invulnerable to injury, and she really did need the bracelets. Later, she was vulnerable specifically to piercing weapons (huh? like D&D?). Now, I think, she’s invulnerable overall. But not getting hit by bullets is still a good habit to have, since sometimes they are made of some alien material and whatnot that could be harmful even to her.

Comment: Perfectly valid points (and don't even get me started on the early days, when her vulnerability was basically a Bondage thing); that said, I wasn't serious -- that was mostly an excuse for the silly comic :)

Answer (score 7):

## Yes.

There are probably numerous Captain America death scenes in the comics; Adamant's answer shows one, here is another.

*Old Man Logan* takes place in a future where virtually all the Marvel heroes were killed decades ago.  Captain America is no exception, and while his death is not explicitly shown, it is heavily implied.

[image: Captain America]

President Red Skull is later seen wearing Cap's mask and uniform.