# Why are heroes without supernatural powers considered “super” heroes?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dc, super-hero, dc-extended-universe

If I were to name a few Superheroes or Villains, I could end up with a really interesting mixture:

Superman, Batman, The Flash, The Joker, Bane, Cpt. Cold, Vibe, Wonder Woman, Spider Man, Green Arrow, Deadpool, Firestorm, Black Widow, Cpt. America, Iron Man, Ant-Man, Nightwing, Domino, Green Goblin, Sandman... and so many others.

The thing is, while Superman (who isn't anything special if compared to his kin), Flash or Captain America are supernatural — as in, they have abilities beyond human capability (superspeed and durability as examples) — others, simply put, have weapons.

Captain Cold, Iron Man, Green Goblin, The Joker, Batman and Green Arrow have no special powers, other than advanced technology, extreme training and being good strategists. While both training and strategy is what makes them special, anyone can do the same and obtain similar results. In fact, if you simply go back in time to the middle ages, and carry a grenade launcher and a machine gun, you would be a superhero in that time period, just the same as Iron Man is for 2016.

I could picture this

> Interviewer: What's your superpower?
>
> Donald Trump: Money

Hence this question: is there any in-universe and out-universe explanations why 'guys with good gear' are considered Superheroes / Supervillains?

Comment: Related discussion, possible dupe: [Are there criteria for being a super hero and does Batman meet them?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50314/5184)

Comment: Also, of note: many of the "superheroes" that aren't supernatural - the general public has no idea of the origins of their abilities or even the extents of their abilities. There was a Batman: The Animated Series episode where multiple people retold a single encounter with Batman, and each one thought they were seeing supernatural powers that were really just his gadgets.

Comment: Captain America is normally described as being a human being at peak capacity (thanks to the super-soldier serum), rather than having power beyond human capability. And I think the Green Goblin in most incarnations has  a serum that *does* give him superhuman strength.

Comment: To paraphrase Dumbledore, it is not our abilities that determine who we are, it is our *choices*. So you're a superhero if you do heroic things.

Comment: RedCaio: But following that logic, Trump, Kim-Jong Un etc would be considered supervillains. And mother teresa a superhero

Comment: One is a superhero if one becomes recognized as a superhero.

Comment: @RedCaio: You are a HERO if you do heroic things. All heroic deeds do not make you a super hero.

Comment: @bobbyalex So you have to do **overly**-heroic things, then?

Comment: Save a life once and you'll be a hero, save the world several times and you'll be a superhero

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ## super:
>
> *extremely good*
>
> ## hero:
>
> *a person who is admired for great or brave acts or fine qualities*
>
> *a person who is greatly admired*
>
> *the chief male character in a story, play, movie, etc.*

**Now here comes the potato:**

> ## superhero:
>
> *a fictional character who has amazing powers (such as the ability to fly)*
>
> *a very heroic person*

- [Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/)

Althought the definitions are very clear, the dates (especially *superhero*'s definition origin) of their origins are *kind of* unclear.

According to [merriam-webster.com](http://merriam-webster.com), the first usage of "*superhero*" word dates back to 1917.  But, of course, in folkloric tales (not in comic sense) similar types of characters such as Robin Hood (15th century) were known with their heroic acts. But he didn't have a superpower. He was good at shooting arrows (and he was handsome AFAIR).

But if we need to work on an example, I can point Tony Stark as a man without superpowers who is considered a superhero. [When Captain America states that when they take his suit of armour and what is left is just but a man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVyoXimCrdQ), Tony says:

> "A Genius. Billionaire. Playboy. Philanthropist." -Tony Stark.

It is his characteristic behaviour that makes him a superhero. Like Batman in DC. You can see the list of superheroes and supervillains without powers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_superheroes_and_villains_without_superpowers#Marvel_Comics_superheroes).

You don't have to have powers to be a superhero (or supervillain).

Comment: "You don't have to have powers to be a superhero (or supervillain)." We know that is you Syndrome

Comment: @user001 _Who's super now?_

Comment: While people like Tony Stark and Syndrome (and Batman, and many others) may not have physical superpowers, their intellect is such that it could be considered "super" given what they end up using it for.