# Is there a superhero who is an actor when not on superhero duty?

Tags: marvel, dc, super-hero

Does anybody know if there is a superhero who is a professional actor when he or she is not on superhero duty?

For instance, Clark Kent (Superman) is a newspaper reporter when he is not saving the world and Tony Stark (Iron Man) is an inventor and entrepreneur. Is there any superhero who is an actor in the same way?

Comment: Does Booster Gold not count?

Comment: Can you narrow this to a certain media? I.e., you are asking about *any* superhero, that could be in movies, tv-shows, books, comics, etc.

Comment: [Madame Fatal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Fatal) was a *former* actor. He retired when he became a superhero.

Comment: [Frank and Leslie Dean](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_Dean_(Earth-616)) had superpowers, but willingly suppressed them so they could live among humans (and star in 'General Hospital') without arousing suspicion.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the question and better phrase what I think you are trying to say. If I misunderstood something, feel free to revert or edit my changes.

Comment: Another way to narrow this question down, besides what Mooz said, would be to add tags for franchises you are interested in. For instance, if you decide you only want stuff from DC and Marvel, tag this question with [dc-comics] and [marvel-comics]. (Or if you are open to superheroes from any company, including heroes from companies that went backrupt decades ago, then just leave it how it is). It might also help to specify whether you mean a movie actor or a stage actor.

Comment: Lyla Lerrol is Krypton's most famous actress; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyla_Lerrol

Comment: [The Jester](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_Powers_(Earth-616)) was a failed actor. Not a hero though...

Comment: The MArvel Wiki lists over 280 characters who've worked as actors; http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Actors

Comment: Awsome link!!! thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, let's try and use our [current superhero definition](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50314/21267).

Comment: If Trish Walker ends up becoming Hellcat in the MCU, then that's an answer, but apparently she starred in a comic book in the comic universe, not a TV show.

Comment: There's Cap'n Oz, although he doesn't seem to do a lot of superheroing; http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/William_Destine_(Earth-616)

Comment: @Valorum Some of those characters aren't superheroes though, like Mary Jane Watson.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Yes, and most stopped being actors when they became superheroes. And many are listed as being actors because of a single appearance in a role at some point in their story arc.

Comment: I've always suspected this of Nicholas Cage...

Comment: Wouldn't this be "all of them that have a secret identity"?

Comment: UFO ran a film studio

Comment: How is this off topic?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### [Wonder Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man)

From the X-Men continuity, Wonder Man is a talented TV actor. His invulnerability allows him to portray his own stunts. Here we see him in ['House of M' #02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_M)  being interviewed on daytime television.

[image]

### [Dazzler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dazzler)

Although she's more famous as a singer, Dazzler was briefly rebooted as a wannabe actress, culminating in the one-shot comic "[Dazzler: The Movie](http://www.supermegamonkey.net/chronocomic/entries/marvel_graphic_novel_12_dazzle.shtml)".

[image]

### [Silk Spectre](http://watchmen.wikia.com/wiki/Sally_Jupiter)

Within the world of the [Watchmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen), Sally Jupiter (AKA Silk Spectre) parlays her popularity as a vigilante into a series of low budget films including a heavily fictionalised version of her life story and a number of deeply 'kitsch' films masquerading as superhero films but in reality, little more than bondage porn.

[image]

### [Captain Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_at_Large)

From the hit film, 'Hero at Large', actor Steve Nichols takes on the role of **Captain Avenger**. While doing publicity for the film, Steve foils a robbery and gets hired by the mayor to help him gain support for an upcoming election. At the end of the film, Steve becomes a true hero by rescuing a young child from a burning building.

Quite how this film missed the Oscar nomination is beyond me.

### [Captain America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger)

For much of his early career, Captain America was an actor working on behalf of the US govt to help sell war bonds. He evidently also made some Hollywood productions.

Comment: It can be argued that Steve Rogers in [*Captain America: The First Avenger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger) was an actor.

Comment: @Mooz - Sure, but he's no Captain Avenger or Dazzler. I'd like to stick to the really recognisable characters.

Comment: That is a great anwser.

Comment: Vixen (Mari McCabe) is a supermodel when not doing superheroics.

Comment: @miltonaut - Model ≠ Actress.

Comment: Is it possible Jackie Chan is actually a super hero, then?

Comment: Dollar Bill could be added here - after all, he was an actor, at least as much as Sally.

Comment: @Gallifreian - I'm not sure you could characterise Dollar Bill's at-work persona as acting.

Comment: @Valorum  -  he was an actor, then turned to crime fighting, but continued to be the face of the National Bank (or whatever). I thought it qualifies, but my reasoning relies on accepting *Before Watchmen* as canon, which I know is a hard thing.

Comment: @Valorum  -  heeey, you could add that Masked-Cutie-something guy from One Punch Man. He totally qualifies. Eeergh, but he's not DC or Marvel

Comment: @Gallifreian - I think you've got the order of events wrong. Dollar Bill was hired by the bank as their "in-house" superhero, then turned to crime-fighting (as part of the Crimebusters) while retaining his job at the bank. Either way, I'm not sure a mascot is an actor.

Comment: @Valorum  -  that's exactly the order I had in mind, although my phrasing might have been poor. I think you're right about the mascot thing though.

Answer (score 14):

Johnny Cage [Mortal Kombat](http://mortalkombat.wikia.com/wiki/Johnny_Cage) was an actor before defending earth realm from invasion by Outworld forces. Depends on whether or not you'd call him a superhero. And technically he wasn't an actor anymore after he became a hero but kept with the whole "defending the world" thing.

Comment: The tags [dc-comics] and [marvel-comics] were since added to this question. I don't think that Mortal Kombat has been published under either of these.

Comment: [Mortal Kombat vs. DC Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_vs._DC_Universe) is a crossover, though.

Answer (score 6):

In Gaiman's reboot of The Eternals, [Sprite](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sprite_(Eternal)_(Earth-616)) has become an actor with the legal name of Colin and the stage name of Sprite and star of "It's Just So Sprite".

"Colin" Being interviewed on the set of "It's Just So Sprite":

[image]

Comment: You might want to mention how this particular story arc ends.

Comment: @Valorum I'm actually in the middle of this right now. No spoilers!

Comment: Ping me when you've gotten caught up.

Comment: @Valorum go ahead and edit the answer, and I'll look at it when I'm done :)

Answer (score 5):

[Blue Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Devil) was a stuntman and special effects specialist who actually became a superhero on set (exoskeletal suit, released demon, magical attack, suit bonded permanently to him).

Comment: But not an actor.

Comment: Stuntman is not an actor, but is related to the same context. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

[Animal Man](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Man)/Buddy Baker of DC comics is an actor as well as a superhero. In the 2011-2015 New 52 series, he won an Oscar for his part in a Birdman-esque film

Answer (score 2):

After Cordelia Chase graduated from high school (*Buffy the Vampire Slayer* season 3) she tried acting (*Angel* season 1), but got nowhere; before long her life was consumed by supernatural struggles.  She acquired some superpowers, though not a costume or pseudonym.

Comment: Cordelia definitely stretches the definition of 'superhero'.

Answer (score 1):

Zenith https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenith_(comics) from 2000AD's stories  originally used/publicised his super-human abilities to promote his pop-star career (which is close enough to being an actor for your purposes, I hope).

Eventually circumstances pushed him to act as a more traditional "superhero", but he remained neutral in outlook.

[image]

Comment: Singer ≠ actor.

Answer (score 0):

Beast Boy/Changeling from Teen Titans. I believe he played in a Star Trek type show.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Teen TItans the TV show or comic? What kind of show? Can you show a panel or screencap/link?

Answer (score 0):

[Charlie Vicker](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Vicker_(New_Earth)) played Green Lantern on television, and his brother Roger mistaken for a real one when he was subbing for Charlie, and killed. Charlie Worked with the Lanterns to find the criminals, and Hal Jordan assigned him a Power Ring from a fallen Corpsman as  battlefield promotion. Vickers performed so well he was made a full corpsman.