# Can anyone please identify this panel? That's not Bruce Wayne, is it?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I **know** I have seen this comic panel somewhere before, years ago, but my mind is just *not pulling up the data!*

[image]

I *want* to believe this was a *Batman* comic, but that just doesn't... "feel" right. Hence me asking for help. It was a story I started, but never finished, and that's all I can remember.

Comment: The characters and their auras appear to be Dazzler and Wonder Man, which would make this a Marvel, not DC comic

Comment: @KMo that was my point. I was sifting trough  and collecting a lot of books, some with similar art styles, and lost track. After an unfortunate flood, a lot of my books were destroyed beyond repair. When I hit upon something familiar, I try to google search it to get the name of the story in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142824/65768) previous unrelated Stack Exchange answer, this appears to be a panel from House of M #2, a series set in an alternate reality where mutants are the privileged class instead of discriminated against, and features Wonder Man (Simon Williams, a non-mutant) being interviewed by Dazzler (Alison Blaire).

A larger version of the panel confirms the identity below:
[image]

Comment: That's it, THANK YOU! I can finally finish this series. Appreciated, pal.

Comment: I have to wonder how a 'non-mutant' could make an entrance like that...

Comment: https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man he is altered human, his body composed of ionic energy. Yup.

Comment: @Jorn there's an **interesting** Nerdsync video on why humans are more or less cool with super humans who gain their power via accident(Fantastic 4, Spiderman, Captain America, Captain Marvel, etc) , but have a natural disdain for mutants. Essentially, normal humans instinctively recognize them as our "Replacement species" and fear our own extinction. You should check it out. What I found interesting is that even the _Inhumans_ don't breed that kind of contempt.

Comment: @rushiro isn't it rather because one is racism meanwhile the other is super human?  no need to  for a superior specie to have racism, just being different provide for unity against scapegoat. . The other one is the old myth of the human transcending its limits to reach half god status.